# Why Opencv wants int32?

Tags: opencv

I got an error when I ran `cv2.fillPoly(color_warp, pts, (0,255, 0))` and then recognized `pts` needed to be `int32`.
But why does it need to be `int32` ?

Comment: Because that's what the OpenCV library writers decided it should be. 32-bit ints are generally big enough for coordinates, so there's no reason to use 64-bit ints. Anyways, what kind of answer are you expecting for this?

Comment: @alkasm I see. Then do you usually check the arguments whether they are int32 or not before you put them in opencv functions?

Comment: Indices are int32 values. This is something that is known from the get-go. Most of the functions operate on images of any datatype. But, you use integers for matrix indexing.

Comment: You can just always cast; generally if you get points *from* another OpenCV function, they will be in the correct format. Otherwise, yea you'll just get used to quite a lot of `pts.astype(np.int32)` and `.astype(np.float32)` and such. Generally it's more efficient of course to use less bits like 32, and the added precision of 64 doesn't always win out when computer vision algorithms are already slow and generally need work to make real-time.

Comment: It totally isn't necessary to allow for indexes larger than 2,147,483,647 (32-bit int max). OTOH an index larger than 65,535 is easily conceivable (16-bit max). So 32-bit ints are pretty standard for coordinates/indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pts` holds an array of array of points on an image. An image is a matrix of Scalars. It is indiced by (X, Y) values which can be stored quite adequately in `int32`.